# cron job fills hard disk

Tags: cron, disk

cron command

```
/usr/bin/rsync -r -t -p --progress -c -i -s /media/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx /media/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx MAILTO=""
```

fails to complete because disk full.

Results of

```
du -s * | sort -rn | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' du -sh
48G     MAILTO=
```

How do I delete this file if it is and how do I prevent in the future?

Comment: If you want to set `MAILTO=""` in the environment of the rsync command, it needs to go **before** it AFAIK. If you don't want lots of output from `rsync` (regardless of where it ends up on disk) then you should probably drop the `--progress` and `-i` options.

Comment: what is the MAILTO= that is filling hard drive and how do I delete?

Comment: deleted the MAILTO= directory and ran cron job but still creating the mailto= directory.  I think my syntax for the MAILTO="" with the cron command is incorrect.  Where should the "MAILTO="" go in the rsync command?

Comment: Either `MAILTO="" /usr/bin/rsync ...` to assign it for the single command, or place `MAILTO=""` on a separate line in your crontab file to assign it globally

Comment: Wow! It took 40 years, but we may have finally found a use case for `set -k` .

Comment: @steeldriver  new issue - made the fix above but now:/var/log/kern.log:Jul 12 12:08:36 jedco kernel: [504382.626681] INFO: task rsync:24737 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
/var/log/kern.log:Jul 12 12:08:36 jedco kernel: [504382.626695] rsync           D    0 24737  24736 0x00000000